# android webview preserve state on orientation change

Tags: android, webview

i have called webview in android now i want to preserve state when orientation changes ,
i had called android:configChanges for activity still not working 
see below

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

what have i to do to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This, It works very fine for me. Add "screenSize" in configChanges

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"